# Hangs while importing data into Neo4j with python

Tags: python, neo4j, graph-databases

I am trying to import [lastfm360K](http://ocelma.net/MusicRecommendationDataset/lastfm-360K.html) database into Neo4j database. I firstly insert all users as node without any problem with following code

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import certifi
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth

driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost", auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "pass"))
session = driver.session()

with open("/Users/inanc/Documents/Software/lastfm-dataset-360K/usersha1-profile.tsv" , 'r') as userFile:
    #first_line = userFile.readline()
    linenum = 0
    for line in userFile:
        linenum = linenum + 1
        if linenum % 1000 == 0:
            print(linenum)
        lineStrip = line.rstrip().split("\t")
        tempDict = {}
        tempDict["user_id"] = lineStrip[0]
        if len(lineStrip) > 1:
            tempDict["gender"] = lineStrip[1]
            if lineStrip[2] != "":
                tempDict["age"] = int(lineStrip[2])
            tempDict["country"] = lineStrip[3]
            tempDict["signup"] = lineStrip[4]
        session.run("CREATE (a:Person {dict})", {"dict": tempDict})


session.close()
```

And then I want to add Artist nodes and relations with users as follows

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import certifi
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth

driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost", auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "pass"))
session = driver.session()

linenum = 0
with open("/Users/inanc/Documents/Software/lastfm-dataset-360K/usersha1-artmbid-artname-plays.tsv" , 'r') as songFile:
    for line in songFile:
        linenum = linenum + 1
        if linenum % 10000 == 0:
            print(linenum)
        lineStrip = line.rstrip().split("\t")
        if len(lineStrip) == 4:
            #print(line)
            user_id = lineStrip[0]
            musicbrainz_artistid = lineStrip[1]
            artist_name = lineStrip[2]
            plays = 1
            if lineStrip[3] != "":
                plays = int(lineStrip[3])

            session.run("MERGE (a:Artist {artist_name: {artist_name}})", {"artist_name": artist_name})
            session.run("MATCH (p:Person {user_id: {user_id}}), (a:Artist {artist_name: {artist_name}}) CREATE (p)-[:LIKES {times: {plays}}]->(a)", {"user_id": user_id, "artist_name": artist_name, "plays": plays})

session.close()
```

It starts doing it without any error (it is very slow by the way, it took hours), but after sometime it hangs at somepoint (for example after a few million lines). Even my python script hangs, I am still able to query through browser.

My only constrains are

```
create constraint on (p:Person) assert p.user_id is unique;
create constraint on (a:Artist) assert a.artist_name is unique;
```

I am using neo4j 3.0.7 on a Macbook with 8GB ram. I am also using the officially supported python [driver](https://neo4j.com/developer/python/) by neo4j.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every call to `session.run()` does the following:

- Start a transaction.
- Perform the Cypher statement passed to `run()`.
- Commit (or rollback) the transaction.

In your case, you are actually making *two* `session.run()` calls per input line. Not only that, but the Cypher statement in the second call has to `MATCH` the `Artist` node that was obtained by the Cypher in the first call.

Since your input file has 17.5 million lines, this means you are creating/committing/closing 35 million transactions. In addition, you are performing 17.5 million unnecessary `MATCH` operations. This is *extremely* expensive, and may also be responsible for making driver stumble at times.

Suggestions:

1. You should batch multiple operations within the same transaction. For example, if you batched 10K operations within each transaction, 17.5 million input rows would only require 1750 transactions.
2. You should combine the two Cypher statements into one.

For example, you should get better results if you changed your code so that it:

- generates a `list` array parameter with each batch of 10K elements, which (if pretty printed) would look like this:

  ```
  {"list": 
    [
      {"id": 1, "name": 'aaa', "plays": 3},
      {"id": 2, "name": 'bbb', "plays": 2},
      {"id": 3, "name": 'ccc', "plays": 3},
      ...
      {"id": 10000, "name": 'xyz', "plays": 7}
    ]
  }
  ```
- uses the following Cypher statement:

  ```
  UNWIND {list} AS d
  MATCH (p:Person {user_id: d.id})
  MERGE (a:Artist {artist_name: d.name})
  MERGE (p)-[:LIKES {times: d.plays}]->(a)
  ```
- calls `session.run()` (once per 10K input lines) with the above Cypher statement and parameter.

Comment: Omg, you were right! It worked like a charm! It did not hang and just took 28 minutes to insert all nodes and relations. Thanks a lot!